# How to initialize a javascript Date to specific Timezone?

Tags: javascript, react-native, timezone

I am using `React Native` to develop a mobile application.

I am getting from the backend a `timestamp` that I need to convert to a specific date format for `Germany Munich` timezone and I need to take care of the added hours in winter and summer.

Here is how my code is working right now

```
unixTime(unixtime) {
    var u = new Date(unixtime * 1000);
    return ('0' + u.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +
        '.' + ('0' + (u.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
        '.' + u.getUTCFullYear() +
        ' ' + ('0' + u.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) +
        ':' + ('0' + u.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) +
        ':' + ('0' + u.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2)

},
```

How can I achieve that?

Update:
Here is what I've found, can someone validate if it is correct?

```
u = u.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Europe/Berlin"})
```

Comment: You can use moment.js for converting in localtime zone, please read this doc
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that I don't want to use a whole library for just a simple conversion. Actually I found something and I don't know if it is valid, I'ill update my question

Answer (score 1):

How about using "toLocaleString()" methods?

```js
let localizedString u.toLocaleString('de-DE', {timeZone: 'CET'});
//and then manipulate 'localizedString'
//
```

Comment: Thank you, please take a look at the update in my question, and tell me if this valid

Comment: It returns "11/21/2020, 11:08:08 PM" if u is initialized such as `new Date(2020,10,22,07,08,09)`. Is it what you would like to know?

Comment: For me it returns: 10/22/2020 6:24:14 , this sounds right, but I would like to have `06` in place of `6`, that that be achieved?

Comment: Do you want zero-padded strings? If so, I'm not certain, but standard library couldn't work for you.Maybe you can handle this problem if you code like this.
http://www.enjoyxstudy.com/javascript/dateformat/dateformat.js

Comment: I ended up using `moment-timezone`

Comment: OK. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) for this

```
npm install intl
```

```js
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {
    timeZone: 'CEST'
  }).format(new Date(timestamp));
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't mention it in the question, but I don't want to use a package for this

Answer (score 0):

you should considering using a lib like moment https://momentjs.com/.
code is easier to write, read and debug.

```
moment.locale('de');
const u = moment(unixtime).format('Y-m-d HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: I tried it, but this gives me wrong date

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `moment-timezone` which gave me the most accurate result

```
const u = moment.unix(unixtime).tz("Europe/Berlin").format('DD-MM-Y HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: Please be aware of [Moment's project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).  You may wish to choose a different library.